# GRPC installed successfully on ubuntu but php is looking for it in another folder

Tags: php, ubuntu, grpc, ubuntu-20.04

Using PHP 7.4 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have installed GRPC using these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf zlib1g-dev php-dev php-pear
sudo pecl install grpc
```

I then added the following line to the folder shown for both `cli` and `fpm`

```
extension=grpc.so
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

When I then run `php` I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

After install `pecl` outputted that it was installed here:

```
/usr/lib/php/20200930/grpc.so
```

Trying to be clever I thought I could just copy the file to where php was expecting it:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/php/20200930/grpc.so /usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so
```

But when you run `php` after you get the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: grpc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20200930
PHP    compiled with module API=20190902
These options need to match
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: I believe the issue was that GRPC was being installing expecting php8, so I changed my application and php version to use php8

That may not have been the solution but I did manage to get this working a number of days later and a lot of different EC2 instances to test on.

Comment: I do recall using a bigger instance meant that this problem didn't happen, so perhaps it's something to do with the install itself?

Comment: Yeah, it has to do with whether or not you have `pear` installed on your PHP instance (when using PECL to install). It also has to do with which version of GRPC you install - correlating with which PHP version you are using. However, I still haven't managed to crack the nut just yet in my instance - when I do, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install with the below command

```
sudo pecl -d php_suffix=8.1 install grpc
```

Initially i had php7.4 and php8.1 versions. Default version was php8.1 and was  trying to install for the same. But for some reason it was installing in the wrong folder (/usr/lib/php/20200930/grpc.so). Removing php7.4 did not help.

Installing specific to php8.1 solved the issue.

Make sure to remove any previous versions

```
sudo pecl uninstall grpc
```

Comment: Sounds similar to what I might have done, I'll tick as it clearly worked for you and might work for others

Comment: This doesn't solve my similar issue on Ubuntu 22.04 and PHP 8.3 (instead of your 8.1) There's no grpc.so anywhere in /usr/local, /usr/lib, /usr/share, /etc, /lib, and so on. And that's because something like this happened: https://serverfault.com/q/589877/327427 . In my case the default "php" version / alternative is 8.3 which produces even more errors from the peclcmd.php and pearcmd.php scripts in /usr/share/php/ .

Answer (score 1):

same issue anyone

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/grpc.so.so (/usr/lib/php/2
0190902/grpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Looks more like a comment or ask this as a separate question,

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30861443)